# How to get a value from a datagridview to a variable VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

Im using a loop to try and pass the values stored in the selected row of a datagrid into an array. However at runtime a get a NullReferenceException was unhandled error saying 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

What do i do???

Here is the code:

```
Dim VenueDetails() As String
            For i = 1 To 12
                VenueDetails(i) = dgvResults.SelectedRows(0).Cells(i).Value
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to initialize (create) the array:

```
Dim VenueDetails(12) As String
```

or

```
ReDim VenueDetails(12)
```

If necessary upper bound (12) can be a variable.